# Why MissingKeyMapError using tag p:gmap with primefaces (in the simplest example)?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, primefaces

I have read that, since Google Maps V3, developers do not need any api key in order to use google map api. My code is the following (the simplest one to visualize a google map). I have tried to run it both on google chrome and on firefox, but in both of them, the map popped up a few seconds and then the app raised this exception:

```
js?sensor=false:32 Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error_.ab @ js?sensor=false:32
util.js:208 Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
```

The code is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <f:view>
        <h:head>
            <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </h:head>

        <h:body>
            Map:
            <p:gmap center="41.381542, 2.122893" zoom="15" type="HYBRID" style="width:600px;height:400px" />
        </h:body>
    </f:view>

</html>
```

In the documentation of primefaces there's no attribute for tag p:gmap in which insert api keys:

[primefaces p:gmap documentation](http://primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/gmap.html)

Comment: so how do you know your PrimeFaces version (which one?) uses the gmap V3 api?

Comment: Google Maps API JS now requires a key: http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.ch/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html.

Comment: Thank you guys. Anyway, in the docuemntation of primefaces there's no attribute for tag p:gmap to insert api keys:

http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/gmap.html

Comment: So you are using PrimeFaces 3.4? Does the newer versions include it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved this by changing the source string in script as follows:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY" type="text/javascript"></script>
```